# Cordova camera plugin windows 8.1 getPicture() method issue

Tags: angularjs, windows, cordova, camera, ionic-framework

When i take a new picture, i get the following error message :

[undefined or null reference error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkJu8.png)

The exception is fired at the following function of the "CameraProxy.js" file

```
function savePhoto(picture, options, successCallback, errorCallback) {
// success callback for capture operation
var success = function(picture) {
    if (options.destinationType == Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI || options.destinationType == Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI) {
        if (options.targetHeight > 0 && options.targetWidth > 0) {
            resizeImage(successCallback, errorCallback, picture, options.targetWidth, options.targetHeight, options.encodingType);
        } else {
            picture.copyAsync(getAppData().localFolder, picture.name, OptUnique).done(function (copiedFile) {
                successCallback("ms-appdata:///local/" + copiedFile.name);
            },errorCallback);
        }
    } else { ....
```

When i debug the application, the "picture' argument of the savePhoto() function seems to be undefined.

My javascript file contains the following function to invoke the camera plugin:

```
    $scope.getNewPicture = function () {
      navigator.camera.getPicture(function (imageURL) {
      console.log("ImageURL: " + imageURL);
    }, function (message) {
      console.log('Failed retrieving picture: ' + message);
    }, {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
    }
  )
};
```

Anyone else came accross this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the plugin version to an older version (1.2.0) and now it seems to be working just fine. (I was using version 2.x before)